# ajaxful rating in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I cant seem to get ajaxful rating to work in rails 3.  Everything installed correctly but I dont know what the problem is.  I installed it from https://github.com/mrbrdo/ajaxful_rating_jquery/ which the author says supports rails 3, but I continue to get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant AjaxfulRating::StarsBuilder::MissingRateRoute
```

but this is what my routes look like for what i want ratings for

```
resources :dishes, :shallow => true, :member => {:rate => :post} do
   resources :photos
   resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

if anyone has any other recommendations for another gem or plugin that does the same thing please post.

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines in your gemfile?

Comment: @Brett I don't think any of these work.  I did some searching everyone seems to have the same consensus that none of these ratings plugins work for rails 3.  I don't have enough experience in rails or ruby to upgrade it for rails 3.  I am just starting from scratch and I am going to roll my own ratings solution.  It would be nice if I could get this working though...

Comment: I definitely had ajaxful_rating working with rails 3 for a recent project, but I'm not sure what the gem you linked to is... seems like a fork with jquery / ajax support perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the gem that worked for me with rails 3.0.7 (from the original author of [ajaxful_rating](https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating)):

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => 'git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git', :branch => "rails3"
```

**Edit:**

Your syntax doesn't actually create a users/rate route (run `rake routes` at the command line from your app to see a list of all routes).  The following syntax is what you want:

```
resources :dishes, :shallow => true do
  member do
    post :rate
  end

  resources :photos
  resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: great! this seems to be working... I was almost done with my own solution haha but the gem is nicer and better coded probably lol the only trouble is I can't seem to get the routes right it throws an error that I need to add a member route :rate with a :post method but I did that so im not sure... my route are same as in original post.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I think i know what's wrong with your routes, edited my answer to include it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give a rating capability to your rails application in Rails 3.1 or higher, you can use the letsrate gem. You can check out from [github repository](http://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate).